# Postgres: Copy (clone) a table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Is there an efficient way in Postgres (with any limitation introduced by the fact its running on AWS RDS taken into account) to clone a table?

Comment: `pg_dump -t tablename`

Comment: thanks; what will the name of the clone be? (I assume the clone will be in the same db)

Comment: `create table clone as select * from original;`?

Comment: select ...into ...